# AJAX request successful but no data can be used

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When I submit my register form, the jQuery sends it to the register.php which then returns JSON data for the jQuery to use.

Everything is working fine - user gets registered. The register.php returns `{"tulemus":"olemas"}` in the network response tab.

The issue here is, although the `register.php` returns data like it should be, it is not being sent to `function(data)`. I even tried doing `console.log(data)` and nothing shows up in the console.. although in the network tab I can see that the .php file successfully returned data.

Register.php:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['username'])){

include_once 'db_connect.php';

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$passwordconfirm = $_POST['passwordconfirm'];

if($password == $passwordconfirm) {

  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $turvakysimus = $_POST['turvakysimus'];
  $turvavastus = $_POST['turvavastus'];

  $sql = "SELECT username FROM kasutajad WHERE username = :username";
  $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);

  $query->bindValue(':username', $username);
  $query->execute();

  $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if($query->rowCount()){

      echo json_encode(array("tulemus"=>"olemas"));
  } else {

    if($user->register($username, $password, $email, $turvakysimus, $turvavastus)) {
      echo json_encode(array("tulemus"=>"loodud"));
    }
  }
} else {

  echo json_encode(array("tulemus"=>"nomatch"));
}
}
?>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(function(){

$("form").submit(function() {
    event.preventDefault();

    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    var passwordconfirm = $('#password_confirm').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var turvakysimus = $('#turvakysimus').val();
    var turvavastus = $('#turvavastus').val();

    $.post("register.php",
    {
        username: username,
        password: password,
        passwordconfirm: passwordconfirm,
        email: email,
        turvakysimus: turvakysimus,
        turvavastus: turvavastus
    },

    function(data)
    {
        if(data.tulemus == 'olemas') {
             $("#resultDiv").hide().html('<div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin-top:25px;"> <strong>Viga!</strong> Sellise nimega kasutaja juba eksisteerib.</div>').fadeIn(1000);
        } else if (data.tulemus == 'loodud'){
            $("#resultDiv").hide().html('<div class="alert alert-success" style="margin-top:25px;"> <strong>Kasutaja loodud!</strong> Võite nüüd sisse logida.</div>').fadeIn(1000);
        } else if (data.tulemus == 'nomatch'){
            $("#resultDiv").hide().html('<div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin-top:25px;"> <strong>Viga!</strong> Teie sisestatud paroolid on erinevad.</div>').fadeIn(1000);
        } 
    }, "json");
});
});
```

Comment: are you getting any error. can you please check browser's console?

Comment: Nothing in the browser console, and in the Network tab you can see that the ``php``` script is returning JSON data: https://gyazo.com/0660e396ac613ff15faadab4ca619707 For some reason jQuery is not getting that.

Comment: There appears to be a `•` character prefixing the JSON and making it invalid in that screenshot.

Comment: So that's what the character means.. any idea why it's invalid?

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, red dots usually represent non-printable special unicode characters.Please check your server side code to prevent outputting those characters.

If your files are encoding with UTF-8, better to encode them with UTF-8 without BOM. This can be easily done through notepad++. The steps are as follows:

- Open your files in notepad++.
- Go to Encoding option on the file menu.
- Then select the option "convert to UTF-8 without BOM".

This may resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`•{"foo":"bar"}` isn't valid JSON. The bullet point is probably appearing due to encoding - `json_encode` requires UTF8 encoding.

You could use something like [`mb_convert_encoding($string,'UTF-8','auto');`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php), but there are plenty of other solutions dealing with UTF8 and json_encode in the comments section on the PHP documentation ([here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)).

Comment: It was working just fine before I started using a class for logging/registering the user. So what's the reason why I now have to convert it to UTF-8 when the text inside JSON is same.

Answer (score 0):

Provide your function as success response and get the parameter 'data' as,

```
success:function(data)
    {
        if(data.tulemus == 'olemas') {
             $("#resultDiv").hide().html('<div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin-top:25px;"> <strong>Viga!</strong> Sellise nimega kasutaja juba eksisteerib.</div>').fadeIn(1000);
        } else if (data.tulemus == 'loodud'){
            $("#resultDiv").hide().html('<div class="alert alert-success" style="margin-top:25px;"> <strong>Kasutaja loodud!</strong> Võite nüüd sisse logida.</div>').fadeIn(1000);
        } else if (data.tulemus == 'nomatch'){
            $("#resultDiv").hide().html('<div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin-top:25px;"> <strong>Viga!</strong> Teie sisestatud paroolid on erinevad.</div>').fadeIn(1000);
        } 
    },
```